# Ingress doesn't work on Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE)

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Below given the config, I am trying to deploy on Google Kubernetes Engine. But after deployment, I can't access the service on the ingress external IP.

I can access the service if I do:

```
$ kubectl exec POD_NAME
# curl GET localhost:6078/todos
```

But I can't access it through ingress. GKE UI show errors like:

- Error during sync: error while evaluating the ingress spec: could not find service "default/todo"

OR

- Some backend services are in UNHEALTHY state

Even though the backend pod is up and running.

I believe there is something wrong with the service.

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: todo
  labels:
    app: todo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: todo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: todo
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: eu.gcr.io/xxxxx/todo
          name: todo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6078
              protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: todo
  labels:
    app: todo
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 6078
  selector:
    app: todo
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: todo-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
  paths:
  - path: /*
    backend:
      serviceName: todo
      servicePort: 6078
```

Comment: The config looks good aside from spacing errors, but the error is not syntax based. Which node version are you using for the cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without knowing what 'todo' does, but there's a few things:

1. There's an indentation error on the Ingress definition. I'm not sure if it's typo or it didn't get applied:

   Instead, it should be something:

   ```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     name: todo-ingress
   spec:
     rules:
     - http:
         paths:
         - path: /*
           backend:
             serviceName: todo
             servicePort: 6078
   ```
2. If you really want `/*` with no `host` then the default backend is overriding you, since it's the last rule in the `nginx.conf`, so you might as well configure:

   ```
   apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
   kind: Ingress
   metadata:
     name: todo-ingress
   spec:
     backend:
       serviceName: todo
       servicePort: 6078
   ```
3. Is your service binding to `0.0.0.0` and not `127.0.0.1`. Listening to on `127.0.0.1` will cause it to serve locally in the pod but not to any service outside.

Comment: the indentation is a typo. About `/*`, I can't really mention any host here right? Because services doesn't have static IP. Also, I want multiple rules to be on that ingress (e.g: `/*` and `/api/*`. Finally, not the server is not configured to listen to `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. Also the application is simple Java Springboot application that is exposing some REST endpoints.

Comment: You can mention a `host` on every rule.